# How to get list of computers names in Microsoft windows network using c++?

Tags: c++, windows, lan

I wants to display the names of all computer and exchange server  in the network same as we see in path Start->My Network place->Entire network->Microsoft windows network.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [NetServerEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. The given [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has a good example.

Let me know in case you in case you have any doubt in it.

Comment: I have already checked this link , it is good but it displays only the name of computers which are in MSHOME network instead of names of all the computers in microsoft windows network.